# 3 Column BootStrap DIV with title div above

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image I'm trying to code divs based on with Bootstrap and HTML+CSS

The image looks like this:

[image]

I'm looking to have 3 of these side by side via bootstrap with 
What I am currently struggling with is the split inside of each  with the top part and bottom parts such as in the example photo.

Is there an easy way to do this? Ideally I'd like the top section of the div to be a different background color, with the image on the left and the text next to it on the right, with the bottom part of the div a separate color.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is easiest with 'Cards' in Bootstrap. Take a look at these docs for Bootstrap 5. If you're using a different version probs better to search for those Cards >>>> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/

Answer (score 0):

For layout, you can use something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
     Column
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     Column
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    Column
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and insert you card instead of "column" word.

[Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4">use BS card or create using div</div>
     <div class="col-4">use BS card or create using div</div>
     <div class="col-4">use BS card or create using div</div>
   </div>
```